# Android SQLite simple syntax error

Tags: android, sqlite

I decided to add a second table for my app. I keep getting a syntax error even though its almost exactly the same setup as the first table creation string.

```
private static final String BUDGET_TABLE = "budgets";
private static final String KEY_ROW_ID_BUDGET = "_id";
private static final String KEY_BUDGET_LIMIT = "limit";
private static final String KEY_BUDGET_CURRENT_AMOUNT = "current_amount";
```

This string throws the syntax error near 'limit'

```
private static final String BUDGET_CREATE =
        "create table "+ BUDGET_TABLE +" ( "+ KEY_ROW_ID_BUDGET+" integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + KEY_BUDGET_LIMIT+" text not null, "+ KEY_BUDGET_CURRENT_AMOUNT+" text);";


db.execSQL(BUDGET_CREATE);
```

Comment: try some other column name than limit as a pre-caution, because "limit" is actually an sql command to limit the number of rows returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its simple, you can/should not use keywords while creating table. You are using `limit` as column which is invalid, hence it is giving you runtime error, i suggest you to change it to something like `budget_limit` like below, and then try again.

```
private static final String BUDGET_TABLE = "budgets";
private static final String KEY_ROW_ID_BUDGET = "_id";
private static final String KEY_BUDGET_LIMIT = "budget_limit";
private static final String KEY_BUDGET_CURRENT_AMOUNT = "current_amount";

private static final String BUDGET_CREATE =
        "create table "+ BUDGET_TABLE +" ( "+ KEY_ROW_ID_BUDGET+" integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + KEY_BUDGET_LIMIT+" text not null, "+ KEY_BUDGET_CURRENT_AMOUNT+" text);";


db.execSQL(BUDGET_CREATE);
```